# how solve this problem so that I can store the string value to this variable

Tags: java, string

String.java:8: error: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to String
lastname = sc.next();

I tried to store the string value to variable lastname but it is showing error that the variable is in compatible to store string value

Comment: I am guessing that you probably named your class _String.java_

Comment: Use `sc.next()` or `sc.nextLine()`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I tried by  using  sc.next() , sc.nextLine(), also tried by casting method but the error was same

Comment: Show your code. There is something else going on here but there is no way of knowing what without looking at your runnable code.

Comment: @KrishnaYadav Did you see the comment from @MattClark?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you named you class `String`.

**Don't do that.**

I mean, you can. But try to not reuse names of core objects.

I used Eclipse to verify and was able to reproduce a very similar message.

```
public class String {

    public void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        //         /\
        // Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.lang.String to String
    }
}
```

If you *really* want to name you class *String*, you will need to fully qualify any reference to *java.lang.string*. The below will work, but you should really just change the name of your class.

```
java.lang.String s = sc.nextLine();
```